# How to get data from closure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote RetrieveUrl class to get JSON data from URL. It all works as expected and I can see that data variable within a closure has a value returned. But I want to show this data in a table within MasterViewController.swift tried several things but seems I have a very limited knowledge about Swift closures.

```
import Foundation

class RetrieveUrl {

func httpGet(request: NSURLRequest!, callback: (String, String?) -> Void)                   
{
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            callback("", error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            var result = NSString(data: data, encoding:
                NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
            callback(result, nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}

func makeRequest() -> () {

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://someapi_url")!)

    var result:String = ""

    httpGet(request){
        (data, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            result = error!
        } else {
            result = data
        }
    }

   }
}
```

MasterViewController.swift code where I want to show this data

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let object = objects[indexPath.row] as NSDate

    // Showing data from URL
    var getUrlObject = RetrieveUrl()
    getUrlObject.makeRequest()

    cell.textLabel!.text = object.description

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why are you making an request from cellForRowAtIndexPath() method? I hope you know that dataTaskWithRequest() will give you data asynchronously.

Comment: This is my first iOs app, I just want to get a data from URL first and then to show it somewhere on a phone screen, so I am not very experienced in this, so if you can show me the best practise it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code:
class RetrieveUrl {

```
func httpGet(request: NSURLRequest!, callback: (NSString, NSString?) -> Void)
{
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            callback("", error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            var result = NSString(data: data, encoding:
                NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
            callback(result, nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}

func makeRequest(callback: (NSString) ->Void) -> Void {

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://sample_url")!)

     var result:NSString = ""


    httpGet(request){
        (data, error) ->  Void in

        if error != nil {
            result = error!
        } else {
            result = data
        }


        callback(data)
    }

}
```

}

Usage:

```
    let retrieveObj = RetrieveUrl()
     retrieveObj.makeRequest(){
         (data) ->  Void in
        println("response data:\(data)")

    }

}
```

Comment: ok, makeRequest() -> Void is still returning Void, if you change this to NSString compiler will ask to add another return section after closure, if I put result there and then in MasterViewController.swift call var returned_data = getUrlObject.makeRequest() returned_data is empty string. But within a closure result variable has data which I need. Main problem here is how to get this data variable from closure to the return value of makeRequest()

Comment: Hi Max, I have updated the code to return the response data using closures. Please see the usage section.

Comment: Thank you very much, this actually worked. Can you please briefly explain what this does [weak self] (data, error) ->  Void in

Comment: [weak self] is not required here. In makeRequest you will pass a callback closure to pass the response to the calling statement in viewController. Once you get the response call the closure which is passed as a parameter in the makeRequest method.